# Is WordPress multisite is good to go?

Tags: multisite

I am planning to make a website for different type of community. For example different types of developer.

PHP
Java
Android
etc

Each type will have different registration and profile fields. Now my confusion is either I should create multisite network where each site will contain different developers or just single site can does this job wisely?

Some stuffs I need is to allow user anytime start to use other sites like if x user is registered for Java and now he want to register for PHP he should able to place his content without register again and user id also should be the same so whenever I fetch content by userid it will give me all data from different site from the same user.

Another question if you prefer to create multisite than what is the best choice.. sub-domain or sub-directory

Answer (score 0):

When multisite is on you have to be careful with your hosting. For example if you want a subdomain installation be sure your webhosting is ready for that because wildcards are necessary (~ subdomain such as `*.yourdomain.com`).

In your case, everything is focused on users. To me you'd better use buddypress because it's a great tool to create community websites and it provide a lot of features for your users.

Even if you start with Buddypress you can move to multisite after.

Comment: I agree! but than if I want to control some premium membership feature within the buddypress it will be difficult for me. For e.g only premium member can make friends, or can create a forum post etc

Comment: No. Buddypress allows you to have a fine user role management. Just read the documentation.